# Unable to start a List View activity due to invoking virtual method on null object reference. Tips?

Tags: java, android, listview, virtual-functions

sorry for the stupid and repetitive question. I am new to android programming and in progress of making an app which can scan QR Codes and save the data to an SQLite database and show it in a ListView of another activity. 
Also, the ListView has a "search" function which enables the user to type text which will bring up a similar result (if found in the listview) from the items in the listview. Lastly, the delete function deletes the item from the ListView when the user taps on the item.

The application worked fine and opened the ListView Activity showing the ListView with the contents until I integrated the search and delete function. 
The application states that I am trying to invoke a virtual method on a null object reference. I have looked up on how to solve it, but couldn't find anything.
Now it shows this error:

```
07-31 18:52:31.688 2900-2900/app.num.barcodescannerproject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: app.num.barcodescannerproject, PID: 2900
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{app.num.barcodescannerproject/app.num.barcodescannerproject.ListActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void app.num.barcodescannerproject.CustomCursorAdapter.changeCursor(android.database.Cursor)' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void app.num.barcodescannerproject.CustomCursorAdapter.changeCursor(android.database.Cursor)' on a null object reference
at app.num.barcodescannerproject.ListActivity.onCreate(ListActivity.java:41)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815) 
07-31 18:52:32.968 2900-2900/app.num.barcodescannerproject I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2900 SIG: 9
```

Here is the code for the Activity which sends the Intent with the data to the ListView Activity:

```
 public void saveOnClick (View saveButton){
    String prescriptionName = scanResult.getText().toString();
if (prescriptionName.length() != 0) {
Intent newIntent = new Intent (this, ListActivity.class);
    newIntent.putExtra("tag_person_name", prescriptionName);
startActivity(newIntent);
finish();
    }
}
```

And this is the code for the ListActivity with the ListView, search and delete functions:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    databaseHelper = new PersonDatabaseHelper(this);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_data);
    databaseHelper.insertData(getIntent().getExtras().getString("tag_person_name"));
    customAdapter.changeCursor(databaseHelper.getAllData());
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(listContentOnItemClickListener);


    customAdapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(ListActivity.this, databaseHelper.getAllData());
    listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    Cursor cursor = databaseHelper.getAllData();


    EditText myFilter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    myFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int count, int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                  int before, int count) {
            customAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
        }
    });

    customAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
            return databaseHelper.fetchDataByName(constraint.toString());
        }
    });
}


//public void onClickEnterData(View btnAdd) {
//  startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class), ENTER_DATA_REQUEST_CODE);
//}

// @Override
//protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
//   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
// if (requestCode == ENTER_DATA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
//  databaseHelper.insertData(data.getExtras().getString("tag_person_name"));
//   customAdapter.changeCursor(databaseHelper.getAllData());
// }
// }
private OnItemClickListener listContentOnItemClickListener
        = new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                            long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        Cursor cursor = (Cursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        final int item_id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(PersonDatabaseHelper.PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ID));
        String item_name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PersonDatabaseHelper.PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME));


        AlertDialog.Builder myDialog
                = new AlertDialog.Builder(ListActivity.this);

        myDialog.setTitle("Delete?");

        TextView dialogTxt_id = new TextView(ListActivity.this);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams dialogTxt_idLayoutParams
                = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        dialogTxt_id.setLayoutParams(dialogTxt_idLayoutParams);
        dialogTxt_id.setText(String.valueOf(item_id));

        TextView dialogC1_id = new TextView(ListActivity.this);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams dialogC1_idLayoutParams
                = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        dialogC1_id.setLayoutParams(dialogC1_idLayoutParams);
        dialogC1_id.setText(item_name);


        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(ListActivity.this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        layout.addView(dialogTxt_id);
        layout.addView(dialogC1_id);
        myDialog.setView(layout);

        myDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            // do something when the button is clicked
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                databaseHelper.delete_byID(item_id);
                updateList();
            }
        });

        myDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            // do something when the button is clicked
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

            }
        });

        myDialog.show();
    }
};

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    databaseHelper.close();
}


private void updateList() {

    customAdapter.changeCursor(databaseHelper.getAllData());
}
```

}

According to what I see, the error is here, at the changeCursor:

```
 databaseHelper.insertData(getIntent().getExtras().getString("tag_person_name"));
    customAdapter.changeCursor(databaseHelper.getAllData());
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(listContentOnItemClickListener);
```

I have also noticed that when I remove the changeCursor, the error will be shown at the setOnItemClickListener, stating that this virtual method is also being invoked on a null object reference.

Is there anything I can do about this? I have searched far and wide across many sites but cannot find the solution anywhere. Perhaps I'm blind.

UPDATE: Thank you for the help, I have realised that I did not initialise the customAdapter first. However, now that I did, I keep getting two exactly same NPE errors as the one with the customAdapater, except the first one is at the setOnItemClickListener and the other at the listView.setAdapter. Both are apparently also invoked on a null object. However this time, unlike with the customAdapter, I really can't spot the mistake. Any help?

Comment: Pleace some log statements in that part where it crashes and establish which object is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initializing the CursorAdapter after its first use. This is wrong as you first need to create the CursorAdapter object before using it.

```
    ...

    databaseHelper.insertData(getIntent().getExtras().getString("tag_person_name"));
/* This line is moved from below to this place i.e before you use the changeCursor method on it*/
    customAdapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(ListActivity.this, databaseHelper.getAllData()); 
customAdapter.changeCursor(databaseHelper.getAllData());
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(listContentOnItemClickListener);

    ...
```

You are getting a Null Pointer Exception (*NPE*) because you are using an object that has not been created yet using the *new* operator

Comment: Dear Narayan, thank you so much for the help! Only just realised that I didn't declare it before using it. However, even upon changing, I still get the NPE but this time it is at the setOnItemClickListener(listContentOnItemClickListener) and listView.setAdapter(customAdapter); Any tips?

Comment: Same mistake again. Your listOnItemClickListener is set later but you have it on your listview before the initialization.

Comment: Or maybe it cannot find the listview in your layout. Does your activity_main have the listview with id list_data. Please check and verify the ids.

Comment: The listOnItemClickListener wont cause the NPE actually. It will just set no click listener on your list items thus you clicking will result in nothing. So just declare the listOnItemClickListener before you set it on the listview so that clicking on list items works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Also should this line go first before `customAdpater` is declared?

```
Cursor cursor = databaseHelper.getAllData();
```